# And multiple values like IN clause

Tags: sql, in-clause

How do I get the Cars and Features which have both Feature1 & Feature2 in below table (BMW and Toyota)?

```
Select Car,Feature 
    from Table 
    where Feature in ('Feature1','Feature2')
```

gives all 3 cars, including Honda which has Feature1 only. This is just a simplified example of the actual query, which can have hundreds of values in the IN clause.

```
Car    Feature
-----  --------
BMW    Feature1
BMW    Feature2
BMW    Feature3
Toyota Feature1
Toyota Feature2
Honda  Feature1
```

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: I would like to have both Car and Feature in the result

Comment: For several other ways to achieve the same thing: [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Car
from your_table
where feature in ('f1', 'f2')
group by car
having count(distinct feature) >= 2
```

Comment: If a car has feature 'f1' listed twice in the table (perhaps unlikely, but it could still be an issue), it would appear as a result in your query. That is why is always use the DISTINCT count for these kinds of queries.

Comment: You are right. I added it to make it work in every case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a GROUP/HAVING construct where the HAVING tests for the number of elements in your IN clause. This way you guarantee that both features are present.

```
SELECT cf.Car
    FROM CarFeature cf
    WHERE cf.Feature IN ('Feature1', 'Feature2')
    GROUP BY cf.Car
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cf.Feature) = 2;
```

Comment: Joe, can I get both the car and features in the result?

Comment: @Kiranshell: Don't you already know the features since you're testing for them in the IN clause?

Comment: Joe, The Car and Feature was a simplified e.g of my requirement, the actual query has hundreds of values in the IN clause. I have to send this result to users after exporting it to a spreadsheet, so I need the features also in the result.

Answer (score 0):

The `IN` clause is effectively a nested `OR`. The following will get you all the cars that have both features.

```
SELECT U.Car FROM
  (
   Select Car from Table where Feature ='Feature1'
   UNION ALL
   Select Car from Table where Feature ='Feature2'
  ) AS U
WHERE COUNT(U.Car) > 1
```